# How to get id of select box after a known text inside label tag?

Tags: jquery

I have a div as shown below.  I know there will be one text "User Type" within a label tag. There may be more than one text "User Type", but only one inside label tag. I need to get the id of tag select coming after this label. In this case it will be user_type_22. How i can get it using jquery?

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="user_type_22">User Type</label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="user_type_22" class="form-control" name="whateverbeit">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it without a loop :

```
id = $("label:contains('User Type')").next('div').find('select').attr('id');
alert(id);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4qzqkhf/

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through all label and get id of select tag like this:

```js
$('label').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).next().find("select").attr("id"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="user_type_22">User Type</label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="user_type_22" class="form-control" name="whateverbeit">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  
   <label class="control-label" for="user_type_23">User Type</label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="user_type_23" class="form-control" name="whateverbeit">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use the `:contains` selector to get the `label` but its text, then `next()` and `find()` to traverse the DOM to get the `select`. Try this:

```js
var id = $('label:contains("User Type")').next('div').find('select').prop('id');
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="user_type_22">User Type</label>
  <div class="control">
    <select id="user_type_22" class="form-control" name="whateverbeit">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('label').each(function() {
   if($(this).html() == "User Type")
      console.log($(this).closest("select").attr("id"));
});
```